# command line and fscanf to parse output

Tags: go

I'm trying to build a small package to parse the command line output with `Fscanf` but get an error

And in the `Command.FscanF` method how to pass on `a ...interface{}` to the next function?

```
package cutil

import (
    "fmt"
    "bytes"
    "os/exec"
)

type Command struct {
    out     bytes.Buffer
}

func (c *Command) Run(command string){
    cmd := exec.Command("bash", "-c", command)
    cmd.Stdout = &c.out
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    
    fmt.Println(c.out.String())
}

func (c *Command) Fscanf(format string, a ...interface{}){
    n, err := fmt.Fscanf(c.out, format, a)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    
    fmt.Println(n)
}
```

error

> cutil/command.go:25:23: cannot use c.out (variable of type
> bytes.Buffer) as io.Reader value in argument to fmt.Fscanf:
> bytes.Buffer does not implement io.Reader (method Read has pointer
> receiver)

```
c := &cutil.Command{}
c.Run(fmt.Sprintf("netstat -nlp | grep :%d", 3000))
var (
    t   string
    i   int
)
c.Fscanf("%s %d", &t, &i)
fmt.Println(t, i)
```

Comment: @mkopriva great :) create an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://pkg.go.dev/bytes@go1.21.0#Buffer.Read

```golang
func (b *Buffer) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error)
```

As you can see the `Read` method's receiver is a pointer (`*Buffer`), which is why the error says:

> bytes.Buffer does not implement io.Reader (method Read has pointer receiver)

That means that you cannot use `bytes.Buffer` as `io.Reader`, instead you have to use `*bytes.Buffer`.

---

To pass the elements of a slice as individual arguments to a variadic function you have to add `...` after the slice argument, e.g. `a...`.

---

```golang
func (c *Command) Fscanf(format string, a ...interface{}){
    n, err := fmt.Fscanf(&c.out, format, a...)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    
    fmt.Println(n)
}
```